# Python requests: Can't send message to myself via Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests, message

I wrote simple Python script that suppose to send message from myself to myself via Facebook.
The problems is that I can't obtain page access token.
Permissions are set correctly.

```
import json
import requests

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'generated this with all possible permissions'

r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', params={'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN})
my_id = r.json()['id']
print(my_id)

r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts', params={'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN})
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = r.json()#####['access_token'] cant be found cos 'data' is empty
print(PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN)

json = {
        'recipient': {'id': my_id},
        'message': {'text': 'Hello'}
}
params = {
'access_token': PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN 
}
r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages', json=json, params=params)
print(r)
```

It's like I don't have access to data in /user/accounts despite that all permissions are set. I only get my user id.

```
11330393********
{'data': []}
<Response [400]>
```

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? recipient id must be the id you get through the webhook

Comment: The 400 response means you sent a bad request. Look into the formatting of the second get request you're sending.

Comment: I thought the webhook is needed to accept incoming messages. Is it necessary for sending messages as well?

Comment: I don't know if it matches your needs, but I made a simple API exactly for that :
https://www.nimrod-messenger.io/